# Compiling python with custom library path

Tags: python, cmake, automake

I'm trying to install the latest Python version on my workstation at work. Unfortunately I don't have root access, and they won't do it for me, so I have to compile from source and put it in ~/local/bin.

I've downloaded the source, and run `./configure --prefix=~/local && make && make install`. However, I get an error that says `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_ctypes'` when it tries to install pip.

According to here: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54094550/linux-modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-ctypes

I need to install `libffi-dev`. So I downloaded the source and ran `./configure --prefix=~/local && make && make install` there.

Now my problem is that it installed the `.so` files in `~/local/lib64`, and the installer tells me I need to link against the library by using `libtool` or the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` env var or some linker flags.

I need to run the python make but it needs to point to both that library directory and the default one. I can't seem to figure out how to do it because none of the options suggested are working.

Thanks!

Comment: Check out the answer in the linked question for a working set of env vars you need to adjust before compiling Python.